# Faced a time out error while iterating through a dictionary, with pymongo version = 3.11 and mongodb version =2.6

Tags: python, mongodb, database-connection, pymongo, timeoutexception

While iterating through a dict and while converting the dict to list facing this timeout error:

13.74.80.60:27017: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6239b29d27b8595095a01a15, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('13.74.80.60', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('13.74.80.60:27017: timed out')>]>

Checked if the cursor is returning data from the db, it did, as soon we try to iterate it throws an exception as shown above.

Comment: please provide the `dict` example.

Answer (score 0):

In pymongo, a connection isn't made until data is actually retrived.

Just setting up a `find()` and retrieving a cursor doesn't actually make a server connection. So I suspect you have an issue with your host connection unrelated to the `find()`

For example you can run this code and it will complete successfully even though there is no client on port 123456:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
db = MongoClient(port=123456)['mydatabase']
cursor = db.mycollection.find()
print(f"No error, here's the cursor {cursor}")
```